# SQL : Monthly breakdown of table using Percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

THE PROBLEM

```
Date          OS        TABLE: OSusage
2018-01-01    MacOS
2018-01-03    MacOS
2018-01-11    MacOS
2018-01-20    Windows
2018-01-21    Linux
2018-03-01    MacOS
2018-03-14    MacOS
2018-03-20    MacOS
2018-03-29    Windows
2018-05-10    MacOS
2017-10-10    MacOS
```

I want to summarise the above data into a breakdown of the previous last 6 months like this:

```
Month      & of MacOS
May        100%     
March      75%           (3/4*100)
January    60%           (3/5*100)
```

This is a simplified version of my problem and this is as far as I've come.

SO FAR WHAT I'VE TRIED.

DATENAME was how I've managed to get the breakdown of months, but even trying to use this again in subquery I'm struggling to find a way of doing the count of the MacOSs.

```
SELECT DATENAME(Month,OSusage.date)AS Months, OS
FROM OSusage
WHERE OSusage.Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())
GROUP BY DATENAME(Month,OSusage.date)
```

Fascinated on the solution & really appreciate any help.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with the ratio:

```
select year(o.date), datename(month, o.date),
       avg(case when os = 'MacOS' then 100.0 else 0 end) as macos_ratio
from osuage o
group by year(o.date), datename(month, o.date)
order by min(o.date);
```

Note that I included the year.  Perhaps you don't want the year broken out, but that is typical when working with months.

Comment: Thanks for this buddy, really interesting how you used the AVG / macros_ratios.  Really appreciate you sharing.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
declare @t table(dt date,  OS varchar(20));
insert into @t values 
('2018-01-01', 'MacOS'),
('2018-01-03', 'MacOS'),
('2018-01-11', 'MacOS'),
('2018-01-20', 'Windows'),
('2018-01-21', 'Linux'),
('2018-03-01', 'MacOS'),
('2018-03-14', 'MacOS'),
('2018-03-20', 'MacOS'),
('2018-03-29', 'Windows'),
('2018-05-10', 'MacOS'),
('2017-10-10', 'MacOS');
select a.yyyy, a.mm, 100.0*m.cnt/a.cnt as pct
from (select year(dt) as yyyy, month(dt) as mm, count(*) as cnt 
        from @t 
       group by year(dt), month(dt) 
     ) a
join (select year(dt) as yyyy, month(dt) as mm, count(*) as cnt 
        from @t 
        where OS = 'MacOS'
       group by year(dt), month(dt) 
     ) m
  on a.yyyy = m.yyyy
 and a.mm   = m.mm
order by yyyy, mm
```

Comment: Mate!! fascinating!! Thanks for sharing your wisdom on this question.. like i said i'm just learning SQL and different ways to manipulate the language, so really appreciate you pitching in.